# My hard drive data was lost during a software upgrade; can I sue?

Tags: property, product-liability

The recent system update named High Sierra from Apple Inc. encrypted my entire disk and resulted in data loss. They didn't inform me that the update would encrypt the entire disk and that there was a risk that it may fail; it did fail, and my data is lost. Is there a way to sue Apple?

Comment: Apple provides some very nice backup software named "Time Machine" for free. It is very easy to use. If you don't have backups, then data loss is absolutely inevitable.

Comment: Inform them first, and see if they're willing to make a deal with you.  You don't want to engage in opportunistic litigation -- it creates a hostile environment for both consumer and producer.  Estimate the value of your loss and see what they say.

Answer (score 3):

By clicking "accept" on the software license, you waived your rights to sue for damages. But you can go to the support forums and make an issue of what happened; Apple - like most companies - doesn't like bad PR. [Official Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/welcome)

Comment: Accepting a software license is like asking users to be lawyers -- it probably would not hold up in court, unless the outside of the box informs them that "in order to use this software, please review the license with a qualifed attorney or technical professional."

Answer (score 2):

Almost surely not. The waivers and disclaimers of liability associated with software from a company like Apple Inc. almost surely insulate them from legal liability. At most you might get a refund of the cost of the system update, but that was probably free.

Comment: Waivers and disclaimers do not insulate companies from liability.  When you market a product to Joe Average, you can't expect them to be professional lawyers.  Apple received no signature from the user which would have provided the user with a second chance to opt-out of the tacit contract between buyer and seller.

Comment: @MarkRosenblitt-Janssen Apple almost certainly  provided the contract and required a specific acknowledgment that they had been read and understood. Click through contracts are legally binding.

Comment: Take that case to court, then, @MarkRosenblitt-Janssen. Highly doubtful you’ll get in the door. The fact that TOS’ contain important information we should read is well known now, if only in some circles as the butt of jokes or objects of disdain with references to “fine print” in contracts. The consumer can’t play ignorant, accept TOS he or she knows contains “important info,” as vague as that may even be, and then sue Apple. Won’t happen. Besides, nobody is forcing you to accept the terms. No gun to anyone’s head to compel them to use MS Office. Therefore, no case.

Comment: @A.fm.:  When you put a product on the market in a convenience store or push marketing to the masses, you are making an implicit "agreement" (in a similar sense as a clickwrap agreement) that you are providing something AS MARKETED (that you don't need to be an expert on anything, not computers and not the law).  What's happening is that most consumers aren't doing any investigation, because the products are OVER-MARKETED and they have an insane trust in the system.  That *may* be the consumers fault, but this answer speaks as if there's no responsibility on the producer *at all*.  WRONG.

Comment: @MarkRosenblitt-Janssen "this answer speaks as if there's no responsibility on the producer at all." Perhaps the reality is a bad one, but it is the reality. Have you identified any case in which a software maker with a clickwrap agreement or the equivalent has won consequential damages in a lawsuit?

Comment: I don't have to identify a case, that's not how the law works.  Either lawyers fight for justice or they fight to win cases.  Which one are you?

Comment: @MarkRosenblitt-Janssen This is exactly how the law works. Lawyers use the tools at their disposal to achieve the best result possible for their clients and the main tools at their disposal are statutes, rules and cases. Generally speaking, lawyers are not in the business of fighting for justice, that would be superheroes. We are honored, however, to be confused for them.

Comment: I am familiar with that argument, which I might refer to as the "Harvard rule", yet I show you the abject failure which the criminal justice system is, so how do you defend yourself?  Also, is this site about winning cases or justice of the law?

Comment: @MarkRosenblitt-Janssen This site is not about winning cases or "justice", it is about what the law is, and not about what the law should be. There are all manner of ways I would like to make the law more fair, but me wanting it to be so doesn't make it so.

Comment: @MarkRosenblitt-Janssen The process of making the law is democratic, but the law itself is made a statutes, rules, cases, judges, juries and lawyers. The whole point of the law is that it prevents people from deciding for themselves unilaterally what is and is not legal.

Comment: @ohwilleke:  "the law itself is made *of* statutes, rules, cases, judges, juries, and lawyers".  There are two points to be made about what you say.  Firstly, notice you said that "law itself is made A statutes".  But you see, I corrected that as Judge because I knew the SPIRIT of what you were writing.  See how that works?  Secondly, the law is not to be composed of lawyers.  You snuck that in there you little thief.  Lastly, you didn't mention amendments (which declare RIGHTS).

Comment: @ohwilleke:  "the whole point of the law is that it prevents people from deciding for themselves unilaterally waht is and is not legal."  This is awful.  What happened to freedom then?  Must we consult the statutes to learn what we can do?  Your liberty extends exactly as far as another's begins.  You can't improve on that.  That's at least one of the basiis of the law.  Refer to the American Revolution.

Comment: Utterly hilarious. Look, judges interpret the laws that are written by legislators. The "spirit" issue you derisively mentioned above is simply that. It is a way of keeping law contemporaneous and of bridging gaps where laws or contracts are poorly worded or subject to unforeseen circumstances. In a common law system (which the US is), lawyers are of course part of the lawmaking process. Aside from the obvious ways, as citizens, their arguments go into the judge's decision. To say otherwise is to say the guy making the mortar had no part in building the house because he never laid a brick.

Comment: @MarkRosenblitt-Janssen "What happened to freedom then? Must we consult the statutes to learn what we can do?" Absolutely. If a statute states that you can't discharge a firearm in a public place, then that is not a freedom you possess unless another statute conflicts with it. That is the point of having laws (the constitution and amendments to it are just special statutes). Revolutions are, by definition, extralegal, removing one set of laws by force and enacting another, although the American Revolution largely preserved state laws and state constitutions with only trivial changes.

Comment: To where do I consult so that I can go outside today?

Comment: @MarkRosenblitt-Janssen If you need to be really sure you consult legal materials, but most of us learn this as part of a socialization into a culture that honors the law and ask professional when outside the domain of applicability of what we know from that process. Often a law barring you from doing outside on a given day (called a curfew or quarantine order or house arrest order) includes a requirement to give you particularized notice of that fact.

Comment: @ohwilleke:  Okay, you have officially left humanness and entered the domain of the computer, which strictly operates on rules.  Had I needed to consult the statues for what I can do for everything I do, I would quickly get so debilitated that I would cease to be a free human and enter the realm of a farm animal.

Comment: So amusing when an online arguer (troll) inevitably enters this late stage of getting literally nothing right. Lazy ad hominem attacks? Check. Nonsensical unrelated arguments ("What happened to freedom then?")? Check. You're good to go, @MarkRosenblitt-Janssen! Somehow the argument is now about when you can go outside. You're wrong there, too, though. States can obviously issue curfews under certain circumstances. You may not go outside then. No magic makes that happen. Just statutes.

Comment: Oh, and "officially left humanness and entered the domain of the computer." Okay, not sure, but apparently you're making this statement without any attempt at irony. Puzzling, but hilariously wrong again. The level of thinking that allows for mass organization and the creation, implementation, and maintenance of a system of laws to govern a society is specifically a defining human characteristic requiring the sort of imagination and intent unavailable to both computers and animals. Welcome to the present.